# What's the different about gcc and gcc++?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I follow my tutorial in linux to install some package:

```
yum install -y pcre pcre-devel openssl openssl-devel gcc gcc++
```

I am not sure about the gcc means `GPN Compiler Collection` or `GPN C Compiler`, I just not sure, because if it means the latter, the `gcc++` maybe means `GNU Compiler C++`.

Who is there to answer my doubts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ["Programming Languages Supported by GCC"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html#G_002b_002b-and-GCC) page:

> The abbreviation GCC has multiple meanings in common use. The current official meaning is “GNU Compiler Collection”, which refers generically to the complete suite of tools. The name historically stood for “GNU C Compiler”, and this usage is still common when the emphasis is on compiling C programs. Finally, the name is also used when speaking of the language-independent component of GCC: code shared among the compilers for all supported languages.

And regarding the difference between the `gcc` and `g++` commands, see the ["GCC Command Options"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) page:

> The usual way to run GCC is to run the executable called gcc, or machine-gcc when cross-compiling, or machine-gcc-version to run a specific version of GCC. When you compile C++ programs, you should invoke GCC as g++ instead. See Compiling C++ Programs, for information about the differences in behavior between gcc and g++ when compiling C++ programs.

and from ["Compiling C++ Programs"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b)

> the use of gcc does not add the C++ library. g++ is a program that calls GCC and automatically specifies linking against the C++ library. It treats ‘.c’, ‘.h’ and ‘.i’ files as C++ source files instead of C source files unless -x is used.

Comment: and you means the `gcc++` means the `GNU c++ Compiler` alright? I searched network there is no related explain.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with yum (my distro uses apt-get packages). In the `yum` command "gcc++" is a package name.  I'm sure it stands for GNU C++, but my minimal googling indicates that the name should probably be `gcc-c++`. If your tutorial says to use `gcc++` and you don't get errors, then you should go with that.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is **GCC** and `gcc++` is **G++** which are both GNU  compilers

- GCC is GNU’s **C** Compiler, and
- G++ is GNU’s **C++** Compiler

The difference is:

**GCC** will compile both `.c` and `.cpp` files. However, it will treat `.c` files as **C** programs and `.cpp` files as **C++** programs.

**G++** will also compile both `.c` and `.cpp` files just like the **GCC** compiler. The difference is that it will treat both `.c` and `.cpp` files as  **C++** programs.